# change filename with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We have some folders that includes some files without extension

for example :

```
/files/a0/ffa5301469e1fb84210e8b5a4a8f3ad3
/files/ff/ff957d05512ea1e71784e811ca45f1f9
/files/f6/f6ffa309ac3fe7fb5b01b07a37bb0d1d
```

as you see this files have not any extension , i want to add extension and change filename with rewrite rule :

for example :

```
REAL PATH : /files/a0/ffa5301469e1fb84210e8b5a4a8f3ad3
REWRITE : /files/a0/ffa5301469e1fb84210e8b5a4a8f3ad3/filename.zip
```

so i need "/files/a0/ffa5301469e1fb84210e8b5a4a8f3ad3" download as "filename.zip"

i tried a lot to edit .htaccess and rewrite rule but i can not succeed

how can i change filename and file extension with rewrite rule ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+files/([a-f0-9]{2}/[a-f0-9]+)($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /files/%1/filename.zip [L,R]

RewriteRule ^files/([a-f0-9]{2}/[a-f0-9]+)/filename.zip$ /files/$1 [L]
```

in the htaccess file in your document root, but depending on the headers returned by the request, it may be telling the browser what type of attachment and filename it should be using, which means what the URL looks like will have no affect.

Comment: thanks a lot , but there is a small problem , filename is not static value , it could be everything , for example `file.dll` or `music.mp3` ,... i want to share links like `/files/a0/ffa5301469e1fb84210e8b5a4a8f3ad3/filename.zip` or `/files/a0/ffa5301469e1fb84210e8b5a4a8f3ad3/this.is.file.name.mkv`

Comment: @user3325376 if it's not part of the original URL, then where does it come from? Mod_rewrite doesn't know anything outside of what the original URL looks like.

Comment: filename and extension came from database , for example REAL FILE PATH is `/files/a0/ffa5301469e1fb84210e8b5a4a8f3ad3` we need to change it to anyname and anyformat 
for example : `/files/a0/ffa5301469e1fb84210e8b5a4a8f3ad3/this.is.file.name.rar` now it should be download as `this.is.file.name.rar`

Comment: @user3325376 htaccess knows nothing about the database, so this is impossible. You'll need to use a script, or add the filename where yuo are generating that link